# Show the convergence of a series. Telescoping?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the series:

$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{k}{k+200}$

Decide if: it is convergent or divergent

Comment: $\displaystyle\large\lim_{k\ \to\ \infty}{k \over k + 200} \not= 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term of the series $\frac{k}{k+200}$ doesn't converge to $0$ so the series is divergent since a necessary condition for the convergence is that the general term converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{k+200} = 1\neq0$

Hence, series diverges.